# Visual Studio C# 2010 SqlCommand Select

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I would like to perform a `SqlCommand` like:

```
SqlCommand com = "(SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE Username = 'Venz')";
```

I really don't know if this'll work! But if it do how would I get the arrays inside com if it met the right condition? Because after selecting `tblEmployee` where the username is equal to Venz I would like to output it like:

```
Console.WriteLine(com.Username);
```

In PHP this is really easy but I'm new to C# so I'm having difficulties

Comment: Check out [Dapper.NET](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) or Entity Framework - in C#, you should definitely get away from working with *raw* SQL and instead upgrade to using an **ORM** that returns nice, usable C# objects for you, from the database!

Comment: Have you ever read the documentation of `SqlCommand`? How many column that your table have? What do you want to get with `com.Username` as a result?

Comment: I disagree, although an ORM seems nice and easy at first you'll soon run into problems. better to just use SqlClient and repository pattern

Comment: Please guys try and answer the question! I'm trying to get an output without using a while loop!

Comment: oh without a while loop hmm

Comment: updated my answer, but yeah if you are looking for a way of doing it in the least lines of code, then an ORM would help. but your question specifies SqlCommand

Comment: what ORM do you use in php?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    string connectionString = ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        string cmd = "(SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE Username = 'Venz')";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, con))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine( reader["Username"].ToString());
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

you can do this without the while loop as follows but it may error if no results are returned

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    reader.Read()
    Console.WriteLine( reader["Username"].ToString());
}
```

as mentioned in the comments on the OQ ORM frameworks like EF can offer shorter, less code, ways of achieving the result. however they are esentaily doing the same thing under the hood

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to learn about ADO.net ( Sql command, Sql connection, Sql dataTable...) at least, look for a begginer tutorials. Then to answer your question : 
Assumes your project has an App.config as shown below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="WingtipToys" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=WingtipToys;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

You need to specify your connection string in order to connect your application to your data source as example :

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WingtipToys"].ConnectionString;
```

Then you must create your connection using `SqlConnection`and your connection string. After that you create the command that you want to excute using sqlCommand. At the end you excute your command and retrieve your data, In your case you use a select query, thus you'll have an SqlDataReader as result. Here you can get what you need using a While to loop your data. Below you find a simple example from Msdn:

```
string queryString ="(SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE Username = 'Venz')";
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                connection.Open();
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", reader[0], reader[1]));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: he you if this answer help you atleast mark it as answer